# Does having a Steel or Silver sword drawn affect sign damage?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Is IGNI damage on The Witcher 2 A.O.K.E.E affected if you equip a Steel Sword or a silver sword in terms that you attack monsters or humanoids, or should you just draw the weapon that has the most +Sign damage?

Comment: Pretty sure its just which one has more +Sign damage. I always could kill things faster with my +sign damage sword with signs. That's how it seemed when I played, anyways. I'm curious to know how :-)

Comment: to be honest, i asked rashly, you have a nice combat log at the witcher 2 where i checked everything out, and its clear that the dmg on signs is only based on sign damage and intensity.

Comment: I'd answer your own question then.

Answer (score 2):

The main diffence between steel and silver sword is that the silver sword deals extra **physical** damage on monsters.

Against monster: silver sword basic damage + monster bonus damage > steel sword basic damage
Against humanoids: steel basic damage > silver basic damage (no monster bonus damage)

**The effect/power of the signs are unaffected by the weapons you are currently holding in your hands. You'll get it's passive boosts just by equipping it.**

The signs can be enhanced by leveling up or some specific equipment that has +sign.

Comment: "You'll get it's passive boosts just by equipping it." Is it true that when fighting with the silver sword I get sign boosts from my steel sword?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I wanted to ask about witcher 3. Is it true there?